# How to get total number of rows in swt.table

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, tabitem

What i want to do is to get all the tableItems from the selected row. but i have find out that the tableItems are stored in indexes  (like in arrary) and not like give row and column and store it on specific cell of table (row, column).

So i have to go through all the next rows upto the end of table and then go through all the rows upto the selected row to get to my required tableItem.

[image]

See image for clearance of my question. The coloured row is the selected one. If i want to go from 'a' to 'b' and then 'c' and so on for complete row, i have go through all the next rows.

so now the problem is how can i get the total number of rows present in swt.table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SWT TableItem IS a row in your Table. You can use it's getText(int index) method to get the contents of the column with index (starting from 0 for the first column) of the selected TableItem.

Therefor the number of TableItems is the total number of rows.